# What is the perfect use case for using Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder()?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

So I am creating this application where there are lots of personal information and data which shouldn't be persisted in the device to avoid security issues. When learning about Room, I came across this `Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder()` which as the documentation states:

> Creates a RoomDatabase.Builder for an in memory database. Information stored in an in memory database disappears when the process is killed. Once a database is built, you should keep a reference to it and re-use it.

I was wondering whether this would be a perfect usecase for my situation. Since the data will only exist in memory and not stored in the device.

It seems like a good idea. My only concern is that I haven't seen an implementation of this in an actual application yet. The only usecase which I saw this `Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder()` used was for testing (so then you don't have to worry about database clean-up on each and every test run).

Can anyone offer some advice? It would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `"My only concern is that I haven't seen an implementation of this in an actual application yet."` - the implementation does not differ from the database that is backed by a physical file

Comment: @pskink yes, I do understand that. I was actually referring to the actual use case and not about the implementation details. They are just the same. Maybe to simplify, my question is just simply whether what I am thinking is a good idea or not? and why?

Comment: yes, it is a good idea - if you want to keep complex data and perform a lot of sophisticated queries on them you could always do that lists lists / maps etc with a lots of code (especially when not using [java.util.stream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/stream/package-summary) package) but instead of it you could just use memory based room database

Comment: Wow! You should post that as answer so I could mark and upvote it for future references! :) Just a followup, are there things I need to look after too by going with this approach?

Comment: On a regular Android device your app process will be killed randomly, and it will lose all data stored in an in-memory database. Doesn't sound like a good idea to me for production use.

Comment: @Uli, Yup you are difinitely right but as my question states, I would not persist the data longer than than the application is active (that includes when the application is killed randomly). So I don't really care whether android randomly kills my process and lose all the data. For some data that I really need to persist (atleast the really needed ones but still should not be stored on disk/device), I plan on using the old bundle solution and onRestore, just re-insert them in the in memory database.)

Comment: Again, these "data" are sensitive information. These could be User Information, Bank Accounts Details, Passwords, and anything alike which should never be stored on device for security purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this same context question in @Florina Muntenescu Blog [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/7-steps-to-room-27a5fe5f99b2)

Her answer was:

> Hi,
>   Yes, it can be used for any use case that requires the data to be kept in memory only. Testing is one of them.

So basically, `Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder()` can be used for other use cases where data should only be kept in memory.

Comment: Be careful as `Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder()` does not support loading pre-packaged database.

Comment: Hi, have you used Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder() in production? Don't you have any issues?

Comment: I didn't really use this in prod... this was just some crazy idea i had back then...

Answer (score 4):

`Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder()` has been designed mostly for testing purposes. I would never use it in production because you can't know when the process is killed by the system, so any use which goes above an advanced structured cache or similar is probably not a good idea.

I think you have a lot of options to solve the problem without relying on this API.

You can use one or more of the following options:

1. Encrypt Room database using [SQLCipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher#using-sqlcipher-for-android-with-room) and store it in application private folder.
2. Use the [Android Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) to store private information or passwords to access personal information.
3. Block some sensitive part of your application if the device is rooted using [SafetyNet](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation.html) api
4. Don't store sensitive data in database at all, but ask for them to the server at runtime only when explicitly requested by the user.

Comment: I actually posted the same question to @Florina Muntenescu Blog here, https://medium.com/mindorks/sqlite-made-easy-room-persistence-library-ecd1a5bb0a2c.. Her answer was this "Yes, it can be used for any use case that requires the data to be kept in memory only. Testing is one of them." So in other words its not just for testing purposes.

Comment: where did you find that it `"has been designed for testing purposes only."`?

Comment: @pskink In all the example provided by Google and not, the API use it's showed only for testing purposes

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones The fact that you want to use it to store "personal data" doesn't change my mind about what I said. You want a RAM db to store data which could be deleted at random times. Why not simply using data structure in app memory for this instead of relying on a temporary db?

Comment: Btw I've reworked the answer because obviously you can use the API as you want (it's part of the public API, nobody can stop you to use it how you want) even if maybe it's not the right approach for your use case

Comment: @MatPag becuase you get many things out of the box when using room. One of which is it reactive nature. When using room you save all the effort for setting up your reactive components. The data is also stored in a structured db which is easier and more readable to query (In my opinion).

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones It's hard for me to believe that you need a lot of structured data to justify the needs of a database, but at the same time something to destroy and rebuild it each time the user closes the app. 
The reacting part can be achieved at the same time using a repository class with LiveData objects. By the way let's go ahead with your idea and see how it goes.

Comment: Moreover receiving -1 without explanation doesn't help anybody

Comment: I haven't really implemented it myself. This was all in my head and I want to have more inputs before even trying to do what I think and so having this conversation really does help. I down voted your answer because of `""has been designed for testing purposes only."`. Now that you've edited your answer I will retract the down vote.

Comment: By the way, you are right with `reacting part can be achieved at the same time using a repository class with LiveData objects`. Thats true but all those things are already available if you use room.

Comment: Thank you for the sincerity about the downvote :) . The only option you have is trying to follow your opinion and see if it really works or not in a real app. Then you can go back here and explain if in the end it worked for you or not, that could be useful for everybody for sure. As I told you, I think you will have trouble checking the database exists each time the user opens your app and if it isn't build it agai. But i'm glad to be wrong on this.

Comment: @MatPag Checking for whether the database exists could easily be handled by dependency injection. I don't think that will ever be a problem. Thank you so much for the inputs! :) I will do try it out on some trial projects I have and maybe go back and update this sometime in the future :) Thank you very much! I love this community coz of people like you :D

Comment: Glad to have started a positive discussion :)